# Make CKEditor image-importer not add sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor

When I import an image in CKEDitor, I don't want it to add sizes automatically.
I don't want this:
[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSwHR.png)

I want this:

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B23y0.png)

How can I prevent the image importer from adding these sizes automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I have the following that removes width/height from the image tag and from the style tag since I auto add a responsive class to the image.

```
CKEDITOR.config.disallowedContent = 'img{width,height}';

CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
ev.editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules(
    {
        elements:
        {
            $: function (element) {
                if (element.name == 'img') {
                    if (element.attributes.style) {
                        element.attributes.style = element.attributes.style.replace(/(height|width)[^;]*;/gi, '');
                    }
                }
                if (!element.attributes.style)
                    delete element.attributes.style;

                return element;
            }
        }
    });
});
```